# How can I contain this image grid within the viewport height without using overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to contain this image grid within the viewport height and it works if I use overflow: hidden on its wrapper. However, I want to add label elements to the images that overflow their wrappers, so I need to find a solution that would keep them visible. I also need the images to stay grouped together even if the viewport is resized (always touching) as they are right now. The images need to be shown fully.

I've added a label example in the first wrapper. As you can see, most of it is hidden, but I'd like it all to be visible and for it to overflow out of the wrapper (not to be contained in it). Any help is appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/k54doq89/2/

```css
#_parent {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
}

#_grid {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    place-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#_row {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

._img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

.label-example {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color:magenta;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="_parent">
    <div id="_grid">
        <div id="_row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="label-example">1234567890</div>
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=1" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=2" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=3" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=4" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=5" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=6" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=7" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=8" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=9" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=10" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=11" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=12" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=13" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=14" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=15" class="_img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it will work with overflow: auto;

Comment: @PetePearl That still hides overflow from the wrapper element. It's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by adding `min-height: min-content;` to the wrapper element style.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#_parent {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
}

#_grid {
    display: flex;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

#_row {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

._img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center top;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.label-example {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color:magenta;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="_parent">
    <div id="_grid">
        <div id="_row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="label-example">1234567890</div>
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=1" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=2" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=3" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=4" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=5" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=6" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=7" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=8" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=9" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=10" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=11" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=12" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=13" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=14" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=15" class="_img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My example work on first browser paint

```css
#_parent {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
}

#_grid {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#_row {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

._img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    display: block;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="_parent">
    <div id="_grid">
        <div id="_row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=1" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=2" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=3" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=4" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=5" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=6" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=7" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=8" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=9" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=10" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=11" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=12" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=13" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=14" class="_img">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img id="" src="//placeimg.com/295/420?text=15" class="_img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I don't think you understood what I'm trying to do. I don't want the wrapper to hide it's overflow.

Comment: You talk about .wrapper ? you want to cut images in .wrapper block ?

Comment: i added an option where the wrapper hides its content without overflow: hidden;

Comment: No, I don't want the images to be cut. They need to be shown fully.